# TypeScript URL Type

Tags: typescript

This is ERROR:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'UrlObject | RouteImpl<string | undefined>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'UrlObject | RouteImpl<string | undefined>'.ts(2322)
link.d.ts(89, 5): The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkRestProps & { href: UrlObject | RouteImpl<string | undefined>; }'
(property) href: UrlObject | __next_route_internal_types__.RouteImpl<string | undefined>
The path or URL to navigate to. This is the only required prop. It can also be an object.

@see — [https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link](vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/sofiu/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html)
```

This is component Code of R:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { UrlObject } from 'url';

interface CommonButtonProps {
    buttonText: string;
    buttonType?: string;
    buttonGo?: string | UrlObject;
}

const CommonButton: FC<CommonButtonProps> = ({ buttonText, buttonType, buttonGo }) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (buttonType === 'Link' && typeof buttonGo === 'string') {
            router.push(buttonGo);
        }
    };

     return (
        <div className="mt-8 text-center">
            {buttonType === 'Link' ? (
                <Link href={ buttonGo} className=" bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-500 text-white py-4 px-6 rounded-lg uppercase">
                    {buttonText}
                </Link>
            ) : (
                <button className="bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-500 text-white py-4 px-6 rounded-lg uppercase">
                    {buttonText}
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default CommonButton;
```

Lastly i try to found solution and come to consider:

`<Link href={{ pathname: buttonGo }}`

I tried to found all sourse of internet. If anyone found `<Link href={`${buttonGo}}`
Then write here this please.

Comment: The TS type error is clear. `href` prop can't be `undefined` if you try to pass a string to it. What's the issue if you use `href={buttonGo || ''}` ?